# What is the actual working of end()

Tags: jquery

I was doing [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/) and I came across a piece of code..

```
$( "#content" )
    .find( "h3" )
    .eq( 2 )
        .html( "new text for the third h3!" )
        .end() // Restores the selection to all h3s in #content
    .eq( 0 )
        .html( "new text for the first h3!" );
```

The comment in the code made me question that will it restore the selection to `#content` or to `all h3s in #content`

Comment: it will reset to the dom object h3
read on the article http://api.jquery.com/end/

Answer (score 1):

Code :

```
$( "#content" )
    .find( "h3" )
    .eq( 2 )
        .html( "new text for the third h3!" )
        .end() // Restores the selection to all h3s in #content
    .eq( 0 )
        .html( "new text for the first h3!" );
```

Here "Restores the selection to all h3s in #content" means it will go back to `h3` in `content` jQuery object to do `eq(0)` with respect to `h3` and not with respect to `eq(2)`.

**[See API Doc for .end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/)**

Comment: But i think it should restore back to `#content` that was the original selection

Comment: @void NO! as you can see `.find()` is used in a context. so the actual selector is `h3` in the context of `#content`.

Comment: no, if you do `.end().end()` (two times) then it will go to `#content`. Here user want to apply `eq()` to `h3` element and not `content`.

Comment: Okay that means, .end() retores to the previous selection?

Comment: if you put  .find(h3).end() then it would go to context